# Dataframe select non aggregate columns value using Group by

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, group-by, aggregate-functions

0

I need to group by multiple fields and pick the record based on max value of a particular columns ( but I need need rest of the columns with values from the same record which has max value for that particular column)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'team': ['A', 'A', 'A',  'B', 'B'],
                   'group': ['One', 'One', 'One', 'Two', 'Two'],
                   'position': ['G', 'G', 'F', 'G', 'G'], 
                   'Serialno': [1, 2, 2, 5, 2],    
                   'points': [7, 5, 7,  4, 9],
                   'col2' : ['No', 'Yes', 'No', 'No', 'Yes']})
```

In this example I want to group by team ,group and position field and want to take max of serial no for this combination and pick corresponding point field value.

```
Expected Output:
A  One   G   5   Yes
A  One   F   7   No
B  Two   G   4   No
```

the tricky part is record 1 and 3 in this expected output. Since they have more than one record in same group, we need to pick the max value of serial no and corresponding points and col2( max serial no is 2 for first group and corresponding points is 5, col2 is Yes, for third group max serial no is 5 and corresponding points is 4, col2 is No)

Please advise how to derive this in Python dataframe.